# How to download large Google Drive file with resume support in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-drive, download-manager

My prefered browser: Chromium
My prefered download manager : uget+aria2

When I download a Google Drive folder shared to me, Chromium automatically downloads it by its default download manager. Problem is the size is really huge. So I got to have some resume support.

Link is like https://doc-00-1s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/bla bla bla bla.

So when I copy the link to uget, or aria2 in terminal... a ServiceLogin.html file gets downloaded.

I have no luck with wget via terminal as well.

So what could be the easy way?

Comment: Ask your friend to split the file into pieces, for example using 7zip.

Comment: sorry, it took him 2 days just to upload the file. There has to be another way.. What is ServiceLogin html file. Is it being downloaded because it fails to verify my google login when i use download via uget or aria? Because if i use the same link again in chrome it works and downloads it via its default download manager.

Comment: Life is long, two days is nothing.

Comment: Have you tried a download manager add-on, like e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn? This one claims to replace the built-in download manager and has resume support.

Comment: there used to be days when uget plugin was available that directs the link to uget . The link used to work in the past, well around 3 yrs back.

Comment: I will give chrono a try. I think firefox downloadthemall will also work wonder. However it would be really nice if uget, or aria had worked

Answer (score 39):

I had the same issue downloading files using downloaders. The issue is when you are ***logged in with any Gmail account***,  google generates a ***different link***. What I do is, I generate a shareable link and open that link in incognito mode, then just added the link to downloader and it works. And now the download link generated is a ***different one***.

**More Clear Solution (Changed)**

1. Open Browser in Private/incognito mode
2. Open the download url  for example it is "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B08CMVb2YK_EMkUyRmc4a0NtazQ&export=download"
3. File size is larger so it will show you warning just click **Download anyway** the file will start downloading.
4. Now goto downloads and copy real link form it, that will be like "https://doc-10-4c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/eia3v63medr04gs1ralifdfml72cmc8k/1469383200000/0595560048316020307/0B08CMVb2YK_EMkUyRmc4a0NtazQ?e=download". For each time/session you will get changed/new link
5. Now add this link to the uget/idm/xdm it will start downloading.

Tools Info
**UGet+ Chrome**

Comment: You don't make sense.

Comment: try it  and let me know if you have same problem as title says. it will make you sense

Comment: "For each time/session you will get changed/new link" - isn't this a problem? How is this an answer if the problem is still there?

Comment: new link is based on time you requested download that have some expiry date , that means the link is valid for some time (let's say 1day). if you want to resume the download and the link is expired , many download have refresh link option so you won't loose the previous progress.

Comment: This didn't work for me. UGet said the download is not resumable and after restarting UGet, I was only able to start from the beginning again. :-(

Comment: you should get the latest link again and update the download uri.

Comment: makes sense :D ... https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012044?hl=en#Download

Comment: Google asks me to login again. Doesn't work

Comment: @elwc make sure the file link is public so you don't have to login into account

Comment: The solution worked for me after changed. Open the link in incognito mode, goto download page by hitting Ctrl + J, pause the download, copy the link (below the file name), paste the link in uGet and taraaa.

Comment: And I almost forget, after completed, if the file name looks like `12fXHWQYWShmeGYlysJJS5I6ZfDa8HwwP`, just rename it yourself to the name and extension of the file you expected to download.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

1. Open Browser in Private/incognito mode
2. Open the download url for example it is `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B08CMVb2YK_EMkUyRmc4a0NtazQ&export=download`
3. File size is larger so it will show you warning just click Download anyway the file will start downloading.
4. Make sure download starts in your browser (I used Firefox 51).
5. Go to downloads (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) copy the link and don't stop the download yet!
6. Paste the link in your download manager, (I used FDM)
7. Soon as download begins in your manager feel free to stop the download in the browser.
8. If the download stops for some reason, just go through the above steps again, and replace the old download link with the new one in your download manager and resume!

Comment: so what is difference with above answer?

Answer (score 3):

> Tools :

- cookies.txt extension
- any download manager accept ccokies files (I use aria2)

> Steps :

- Download cookies of the tab.
- load the cookies to the download manager (I am using aria2).
- Start download.

> Ex:.

```
aria2c --load-cookies=cookies.txt  <Download-Url>
```

Comment: Thank you. None of the above answers were working.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this might solve the issue in a clever & useful way

**Tools used:**

- wget
- uGet (or any other Download Manager)

**Things to do:**

- Open terminal
- Set this command -> `nano ~/.bash_aliases`
- Copy and paste this function into the terminal

  ```sh
  gdrive_download () {
    CONFIRM=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')
    wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$CONFIRM&id=$1" -O $2
    rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
  }
  ```
- Save file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- On terminal, call the function (this is an example)

  ```
   gdrive_download long_google_drive_file_id filename.ext
  ```
- Once it run, you will see an url "https://..."
- copy and paste this url in your uGet > New Download > URI
- Enjoy.

Tested to this date.

The function `gdrive_download` comes from [vladalive's comment](https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805/f4f0900a4936144a1843c50ce0fdeed2c540631e#gistcomment-2359248), using the one-line command from [beliys](https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805/f4f0900a4936144a1843c50ce0fdeed2c540631e#gistcomment-2316906).

They're whom deserve such credit.

Comment: I think it may work, the gist itself is actually incomplete, the comments there have the full answer! I will see if I can make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

**You may get a direct link of the file by using the DriveAPI:**

1. First set your file view permission to `Anyone With the Link`.
2. Copy the `File ID`, which is the string between `drive.google.com/file/d/` and `/view?usp=sharing`
3. Go to [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
4. Click `CREATE CREADENTIALS` on the top of the page, then `API Key`.
5. Copy the API Key and build the link with following syntax:
   `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[YOUR_FILE_ID_HERE]?alt=media&key=[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]`

**Note: The file downloaded via this method won't have extension, the filename is same as your File ID**

Answer (score 0):

Updating my IDM to the latest version did the trick for me. Once I updated IDM to the latest version it automatically added an extension to chrome. I, then restarted chrome in normal mode, pasted the url and hit on "Enter" and IDM popped up with the proper link for the file to be downloaded. I'm happily downloading the file with IDM now. The file size is approx. 2.5 GB.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found this way extremely easy.

First, I have to say it would be helpful if you want to download a file whose link expired using the IDM (Internet Download Manager) application.

So do these steps:

1-download the file with IDM

[Image Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MMyc.png)

2-after a while, the link will be expired, and IDM will not continue to download the file. So stop the download, do a right-click on the file in IDM and choose refresh download address

[Image Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKnKn.png)

3-then you will go to the first download page that has a download link in it, click on download (in some cases, it's `download anyway`) you will get a message that says

> is this your new link? (or something like that) , so click on yes, it will be the message you that
> your link refresh successfully (or again, something like that!)

[Image Step 3-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP1N7.png) [Step 3-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNMlE.png) [Step 3-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyFAH.png)

4- go back to the IDM, right-click on the file, and choose resume download. your file will continue to download

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLCcZ.png)